# Python result (list?) to docx for my Warehouse

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I can't figure something out
The idea is to create an automatic warehouse label creator "template".
What is suposed to do is create a .docx document (using python-docx) with all the individual locations of an specific shelf within my warehouse (A real warehouse with forklifts and everything), so I can print them out from Microsoft Word.

This is the code I managed to work out so far:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()

try:
    letter = input("Please select the row: ")
    rack = input("Please select the column from the row: ")


    amount_of_locations = input("Please insert the amount of locations in the selected row and column: ")


    amount_of_locations = int(amount_of_locations)

    for result in (range (1, amount_of_locations + 1)):
        label_list = (letter + rack + (" - ") + str(result))
        print(label_list)

    

except:
    print("Please select a numeric value to define the amount of locations")
    quit()

document.add_heading(label_list)

document.save("Labels For " + str(letter) + str(rack) + ".docx")
```

[I was expecting the Word document to print out a list like the cmd did in this image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTefw.png)

[But word will just "print" this, which is just: letter + rack + (" - ") + amount_of_locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQivC.png)

So basically what I want to happen is that the stuff that appears in cdm to appear exactly the same in word.

Sorry if I'm not using correct terms (Which I'm sure it's the case), but it is one of my first projects and should make the work I'm suposed to manually do a whole of a lot more easy and efficient.

Sorry again and thanks for your time
Any help is gladly appreciated :)

Comment: You should do `document.add_heading(label_list)` in the loop. At the moment this is only called once after the loop and `label_list` contains the last value it was given in the loop.

Comment: BTW, the `try`-block is far too big, you should not use a bare `except:` clause (see the [Style Guide for Python code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)), and according to the documentation [`quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=quit#constants-added-by-the-site-module) should not be used in programs.